# Is an abstract ViewModel considered a Model when it is inherited?

Tags: c#, mvvm, terminology

If I have an abstract ViewModel (VM-A), which is inherited by child ViewModels (VM-B,C,D), is that ViewModel (VM-A) considered a model of ViewModels?

Example: VM-A is a "Shape" class contains *x* number of common properties, with abstract Calculate() method.

VM-B is a "Circle" class, inheriting VM-A, and the overrides Calculate to perform its own calculations using the common properties.

Is VM-A considered a Model at that point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is considered a base ViewModel. The concept **Model** refers to either a domain model which represents the real state content (an object-oriented approach), or the data access layer that represents that content (a data-centric approach).